# Does a async function which returns Promise<void> have an implicit return at the end of a block?

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

```
public async demo(): Promise<void> {
    // Do some stuff here
    // Doing more stuff
    // ... 
    // End of block without return;
}
```

Is a new `Promise<void>` returned implicitely at the end of the block in TypeScript/ES6?

Example for boolean type:

```
class Test {

    public async test(): Promise<boolean> {
        return true;
    }

    public main(): void {

        this.test().then((data: boolean) => {

            console.log(data);

        });

    }

}

new Test().main();
```

This prints `true` to the console because a `return` inside of a async function creates a new `Promise` and calls `resolve()` on it with the returned data. What happens with a `Promise<void>`?

Comment: Every JavaScript/TypeScript function has an implicit return at the end if you don't put one there explicitly.

Comment: @str: When I return from a async function something, doesn't that implicitly return a new Promise instance, calling `.resolve()` on it with the return data, and when throwing a exception `.reject()` respectively?

Comment: Yes, async functions always return a promise.

Comment: A `Promise<void>` can be resolved just like any other Promise.

Comment: My question is: When I don't return anything in a function that returns `Promise<void>`, ie. `return` or `return void` is not called, is it called implicitly at the end of the function block?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

> What happens with a Promise

Same thing with a function that returns `void`. A `void` function returns `undefined`. A `Promise<void>` resolves to an `undefined`.

```
function foo(){}; console.log(foo()); // undefined
async function bar(){}; bar().then(res => console.log(res)); // undefined
```

Comment: As per the second line in your code snippet, is `Promise<void>` the default type inferred by the TypeScript compiler when it sees an async function?

Comment: If its async its always `Promise<something>`. If the function is async and doesn't return anything then its `Promise<void>` 

Comment: Another question: even if I do not call then method, the async funtion will execute? Once is a Promise<void> function, it doesn't matter what is returned, right?

Comment: `even if I do not call then method, the async funtion will execute?` Yes. In this case you are simply ignoring the result (the returned `Promise`) of the function. It doesn't matter if you use the result of the function (e.g call a `then` on the returned `Promise`) or not 

Comment: @basarat say if an async function returns an object, but we have not defined its return type explicitly in fn definition, what does TypeScript assume the return type here? Will it be `Promise<any>` or `any` only or something else? If it is second, then does it mean that `Promises` come under `any` type?

Comment: @user7630232 It will be `Promise<inferred type of the returned object>`